# removing \r as they go into syslog file

Tags: linux, syslog

I have an app being written to work both on Linux and Windows. For portability, new line is taken as \r\n. This app is logging some useful information to debug. It is the syslog which logs the information in Linux. When open the syslog file, all the \r characters are appeared as ^M. I have found that using dos2unix on syslog file will remove ^M. But I want to remove ^M as they go into syslog. If there is any configuration setting or any other workaround other than changing the code(using #ifdefs), somebody please provide. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't write \r's if you're not on Windows.

You can define a NEWLINE constant, like so:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#define NEWLINE '\r\n'
#else
#define NEWLINE '\n'
#endif
```

and use it.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978081/android-background-service-keep-alive-if-app-crashes) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Its not "portable" to use Windows new lines in Linux.

You *should* change the code, and not log either \r or \n in Windows or Linux, its bad practice to log new lines in syslog since "traditional" logging formats delimit files with \n. If you have any extra \n tools which read files will break. Usually any text on a new line delimited file that's not starting with "<" is dropped.

If you are using rsyslog you can use *drop-cc* to strip control characters in the messages.